# Is there a way to check for duplicate lines within a file using Java?

Tags: java, file, duplicates, iostream, writer

I'm attempting to read each line within an .inp file and for every non-duplicate, write the line to a new file. The issue I'm running into with the code I have so far is that all lines are written into the output file, regardless of if they're duplicates of previous line(s) or not. I'm using a Scanner object to read the file and a BufferedReader/FileWriter object to write the output file.

How do I avoid writing the duplicates?

```java
String book = reader.nextLine();
boolean duplicate = false;

while (reader.hasNext() == true) {
    try {
        duplicate = reader.hasNext(book);

        if (duplicate == true) {
            book = reader.nextLine();
        } else {
            writer.write(book + "\n");
            book = reader.nextLine();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can store a hash (System.identityHashCode(string)) of each string in a Set (but don't forget about memory limits, this solutions will work for 1000 strings, but not sure if it will be ok for 1 000 000 strings).

Comment: Are you saying that duplicate lines appear together in the file? Cannot, for example, line 96 be a duplicate of line 70? Also, can you [edit] your question and post some sample lines from the file? By the way, how many lines are there in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the situation:

- If the duplicate lines are sequential, maintain a variable to store the previous line and compare against it.
- If the duplicate lines are not sequential, and there are relatively <sup>(*)</sup> few short lines, store the lines you've already processed in a `HashSet` and upon processing a line check whether the set already `contains()` the line or not.
- If the duplicate lines are not sequential, and there are relatively <sup>(*)</sup> few but long lines, instead of storing the complete lines in a `HashSet`, store a hash (e.g. SHA1) of each line, and compare against that.
- If the duplicate lines are not sequential, and there are a lot of long lines, combine the techniques described above with some form of persistent database or data store.

---

<sup><sup>(*)</sup> Relative to available memory</sup>